# Nodejs server takes multiple process

Tags: node.js

I'm facing a problem with nodejs on a server.

When I launch this simple node program on my server with `node server.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello');
});

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('App listening on port 4000'));
```

It takes several (7) process on my Cpanel dashboard (see images) and I try to figure out why.

[Process count without node server running - 2 process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Pnx.png)

[Process count with node server running - 9 process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Rfhg.png)

If I run a `ps aux` on the server, it said that there is only one node process running, but Cpanel count 7 process for this simple server. When I go to the "Resource usage" page on Cpanel, it shows a list with the same process and the same id, several times (7).

Is it normal ? And if it's not, how can I run a node server on 1 single process ?

Thanks for reading and I hope this question is understandable.

Comment: see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15885457/9681220

Comment: and see this two link: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2 - https://github.com/foreversd/forever maybe -- help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were to guess, I'd say that your cPanel is showing the number of threads that are active when you run node.

Node is said to be single-threaded, and that is true from the perspective of the user, but in actuality, Node runs several threads: 1 in the foreground for your user-space program and a variable number to handle async events like file io and reacting to the network.